# looping through an array

Tags: php

My question is how to stick array values into variables as I loop through them.

I am using this to fetch my array - I need two values from the query.

```
$categ = array();   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($categ, array(
        'cat' => $row["CategoryName"],
        'course' => $row["Course"]
    ));
}
```

There are duplicates here so I use the following to get a unique array:

```
$categ = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $categ)));
```

This gives the following output:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array ( [cat] => Dogs [course] => Kempton Park )
  [2] => Array ( [cat] => Dogs [course] => Lingfield Park )
  [4] => Array ( [cat] => Gallops [course] => Wincanton )
)
```

I then want to loop through this array allocating the values of [cat] and [course] to two variables: `$cat` and `$course`

I have tried all sorts but it's not working: The below gives a syntax error - not sure why??

```
foreach ($categ as list($cat2, $course2)){
    require ('C04_by_Account_by_Bet.php');
};
```

Comment: `foreach ($categ as list($cat2, $course2))` is `PHP 5.5`

Comment: Why do you want to `require` a file over and over again??

Comment: @Baba: You can seriously do that?

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes you can see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/foreachlist

Comment: @RocketHazmat you can see all other functions at https://wiki.php.net/rfc

Comment: For your interest: the file is a report - i am generating it repeatedly for output based upon all the array variables

Comment: ok PHP 5.5 is my problem

Comment: Multiple `require` would generate errors ... why not look for a better approach ... like session or client - reporting server approach ..

Comment: Thanks Baba - I wish I knew more about reporting server approach - this process seems to work without error at present but I suspect its not the best way - just one way I can get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$categ = array();   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->cat = $row["CategoryName"];
    $obj->course = $row["Course"];
    $categ[] = $obj;
}

foreach($categ as $thing)
{
    $thing->cat;
    $thing->course;
}
```

I would recommend something like this.

EDIT: Or even better

```
$categ = array();   
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $categ[] = $obj;
}

foreach($categ as $thing)
{
    $thing->cat;
    $thing->course;
}
```

Comment: I have opted for this method in the end:


    foreach ($categ as $row){
    $cat = $row['cat'] 
    $category = $row['course']
    };

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `list()` in a `foreach` like that.  You need to do it like this:

```
foreach ($categ as $value){
    list($cat2, $course2) = $value;
}
```

**EDIT**: You *can* do `foreach ($categ as list($cat2, $course2)){` in PHP 5.5+

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this:

```
$categ = array();   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $categ[$row["CategoryName"]][] = $row["Course"];
}
```

array will be

```
Array (
  [Dogs] => Array ( Kempton Park, Lingfield Park ),
  [Gallops] => Array ( Wincanton )
)
```

then you can do:

```
foreach($categ as $category => $courses) {
   $courses = array_unique($courses);
   foreach($courses as $course) {
      echo $category . ' : ' . $course; //or any other action
   }
}
```